# HEROKU 20 - RUBY 2.7.2 / 401 Unauthorized Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems, bcrypt

I have a problem with ruby.

In my current project the version of ruby is 2.5.7. As Heroku 16 is deprecated soon, i update the version to 2.7.2.

```
~ $ ruby -v
ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [x86_64-linux]
~ $ rails -v
Rails 5.2.4
~ $ yarn -v
1.22.4
~ $ npm -v
6.14.4
~ $ gem -v
3.1.4
~ $ bundle -v
Bundler version 2.2.11
```

after deploying i get this errors

```
 [1m[36mUser Load (2.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["email", "admin@gmail.loc"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2021-04-02T05:20:07.546331+00:00 app[web.1]:   ↳ app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:17
2021-04-02T05:20:07.616185+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[36mStore Load (1.8ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "stores".* FROM "stores" WHERE "stores"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "stores"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2021-04-02T05:20:07.616410+00:00 app[web.1]:   ↳ app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:19
2021-04-02T05:20:07.722570+00:00 app[web.1]:   [1m[36mUser Load (1.9ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."email" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2[0m  [["email", "admin@gmail.loc"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2021-04-02T05:20:07.722777+00:00 app[web.1]:   ↳ app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:11
2021-04-02T05:20:07.881387+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/login" host=garni-qa-4.herokuapp.com request_id=e5e9abea-4907-46c1-8808-947deabfec4f fwd="37.252.74.244" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=397ms status=302 bytes=746 protocol=https
2021-04-02T05:20:07.875899+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 401 Unauthorized in 342ms (ActiveRecord: 16.0ms | MongoDB: 0.0ms)
2021-04-02T05:20:08.038364+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/login" for 37.252.74.244 at 2021-04-02 05:20:08 +0000
2021-04-02T05:20:08.042413+00:00 app[web.1]: Cannot render console from 37.252.74.244! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
2021-04-02T05:20:08.069641+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
2021-04-02T05:20:08.073868+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendering sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/_application
2021-04-02T05:20:08.083779+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/_application (9.8ms)
2021-04-02T05:20:08.314009+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/login" host=qa-4.herokuapp.com request_id=20cbbb7e-4438-414e-97e3-b82ad40112cb fwd="37.252.74.244" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=279ms status=200 bytes=21277 protocol=https
2021-04-02T05:20:08.309887+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 240ms (Views: 237.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | MongoDB: 0.0ms)
```

here is my rake routes

```
 new_user_session GET            /login(.:format)                                                                         sessions#new
                             user_session POST           /login(.:format)                                                                         sessions#create
                     destroy_user_session DELETE         /logout(.:format)                                                                        sessions#destroy
                        new_user_password GET            /password/new(.:format)                                                                  devise/passwords#new
                       edit_user_password GET            /password/edit(.:format)                                                                 devise/passwords#edit
                            user_password PATCH          /password(.:format)                                                                      devise/passwords#update
                                          PUT            /password(.:format)                                                                      devise/passwords#update
                                          POST           /password(.:format)                                                                      devise/passwords#create
                 cancel_user_registration GET            /register/cancel(.:format)                                                               devise/registrations#cancel
                    new_user_registration GET            /register/sign_up(.:format)                                                              devise/registrations#new
                   edit_user_registration GET            /register/edit(.:format)                                                                 devise/registrations#edit
                        user_registration PATCH          /register(.:format)                                                                      devise/registrations#update
                                          PUT            /register(.:format)                                                                      devise/registrations#update
                                          DELETE         /register(.:format)                                                                      devise/registrations#destroy
                                          POST           /register(.:format)                                                                      devise/registrations#create
                                     root GET            /                                                                                        home#index
                                 new_user GET            /new_user(.:format)
```

I remove bundle, update npm , yarn, install bundle

```
rm vendor/bundle -r
gem install bundler && gem install rails
bundle install
bundle update --ruby
```

```
2021-04-01T09:53:12.483682+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/login" host=qa-3.herokuapp.com request_id=5610e1a6-b2a6-496-84e4-80f539106abf
```

I think the problem is in bcrypt/ubuntu/rails versions
`Completed 401 Unauthorized`

But cann't solve it. Any idea what else can I do, to fix it? It's a routing error, but I cann't find the way to fix it.

Comment: rails version not changed - still using Rails 5.2.4

Comment: Yes, in local i run ./bin/webpack-dev-server command, in heroku i run the same command. but it don't works

Comment: Thanks. 
It must installed with npm, may be some problem was with it, but i have problem with rails routing. Missing js file don't harm to my system, when i fill my form it's redirecting to some  page. I don't get any error, just 200 success. So i  cann't find the way to install it in heroku. In local i upgrade version and it works. but in HEROKU it didn't works. So i need to know may be for heroku i need to run smth else or the problem is in versions so i need to change them? Any idea?

Comment: any luck following something like: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs

Comment: i fix all my js errors, but i still have routing problem.

Comment: can you post your `routes.rb`, and the output of your `rake routes`?

Comment: I add rake routes in post. In heroku16/18 i don't have a problem with login. Just after update ruby version from  2.5.5 to 2.7.2 and updating heroku to 20

Comment: I don't find any way so I just change heroku 20 to heroku 18(ubuntu 20.04 there is a problem with bcrypt, so i use ubuntu 18).

Comment: sorry, just re-read your "errors", and can't see an actual error in there.  have you checked that the database holds your username and password?  are you using devise?

Comment: yes, the problem is in ubuntu bcrypt version ) thanks

Comment: is this standard "out of the box" `devise`?  have you tried to reset your password at the rails console?

Comment: yes, i tried, thank you Jad, but the problem is with ubuntu 20, and i don't want to change whole my gem file only for bcrypt. So I solve the problem using Heroku 18. I just update some gems, and ruby version. Whole project works correctly.